# 'The method or operation is not implemented' in Xamarin Forms when using Named Pipe

Tags: c#, xamarin

First of all, hello everyone as it's my first post.

Getting to the case: I'm trying to send message between two apps - one on computer and the other on Android through Named Pipes and executing the following code ends up with an **"The method or operation is not implemented"** exception.

The code fragment is an *Button Clicked* event - the idea is to open a pipe, send through a button text (buttons texts are "Up", "Down", "Left" and "Right) and then close the pipe.

I've tested this and it works as long as the project is a WinForms project using standard System.IO.Pipes.

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        header.Text = "Pressed: " + (sender as Button).Text;
        try
        {
            using (var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(SERVERNAME, "testpipe", PipeDirection.Out))
            {
                header.Text = "Connected with: " + SERVERNAME;
                using (var stream = new StreamWriter(pipeClient))
                {
                    pipeClient.Connect();

                    stream.Write((sender as Button).Text);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);
            Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

The line creating an exception is

```
using (var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(SERVERNAME, "testpipe", PipeDirection.Out))
```

I've tested servername (const string) being an IP address, "localhost" or computer name and nothing changes.
Am I doing something wrong or is this a Xamarin error?

Comment: Good formating on your first question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the [mono source for `NamedPipeClientStream`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/f460c9bb83658ccc6bd3caf958d82bd58a67b6a4/mcs/class/System.Core/System.IO.Pipes/NamedPipeClientStream.cs) this is only implemented for win32. So it makes sense that you are getting a `NotImplementedException`.

Not every API that you have available on the desktop is supported on mobile.

Instead of using `NamedPipeClientStream` you could use TCP Sockets or something more high level as a ASP.NET Core server exposing what you need as a RESTful API or similar and consuming it with HttpClient or any other REST client.

Comment: Ach, I thought that if that method is mentioned in Xamarin documentation it would work, but I guess was wrong.
Found a very simple HelloWorld TCP Socket app that exactly suits my needs, so that problem is solved. Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: It is mentioned there, where you can see in the Syntax section that it is only for Win32. If my answer, answered your question about NamedPipeClientStream, please mark it as such.